# Electron net request disable dialog... program freezes

Tags: node.js, request, electron

I am using `net.request` by electron, and sometimes I run into errors like this [image]

here is a sample code from the electron's page itself,

```
const { app } = require('electron')
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const { net } = require('electron')
  const request = net.request('https://github.com')
  request.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`)
    })
    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log('No more data in response.')
    })
  })
  request.end()
})
```

So this error is not a big problem for me, but when this dialog pops, I want it to ignore that error and just keep running the program. Instead it freezes until I click `OK`.

I am running a server and I will have to drop requests with error but i dont want my server to fully stop until interaction, how can I disable this box or ignore errors ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`process` is a built-in variable in nodejs, and doesn't need to be defined. While an exception happens, nodejs will behave natural and prompt an error dialog unless its method is defined to override anywhere in the program.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {})
```

Referring [to the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html), any of the events could be overridden in the program by just redefining the events' methods in the program.

As an example, if I use this code in my program, I do not see ANYTHING related to the error, because this function has overridden built-in nodejs behavior.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I submitted the update.. @Tyler2P